# Where is Exit Time Condition in Unity5

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity 4 we have option for animation conditions's like Exit Time or Attak Mode Or another Options But In Unity5 i can't find these options 
where is Exit Time Condition in Unity5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see it here in [Animation Transition](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html) :

[image]

Comment: Ok . in unity4 it was inside conditions but in unity5 we must Check Has Exit Time and then set Time and it's DIFFERENT . thanks by this picture my problem solved